# What happens if data gets inserted in the middle of a transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to database and I'm lost with [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). For example
in a situation where I have a table `sensor_log` that receives INSERT constantly and I want to move data to two other tables in one transaction.

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO sensor_log_a
SELECT id, location 
FROM sensor_log
INNER JOIN sensor_location_to_insert USING (location);

INSERT INTO sensor_log_b
SELECT id, location 
FROM sensor_log
INNER JOIN sensor_location_to_insert USING (location);

COMMIT;
```

Is there a risk that data is different between sensor_log_a and sensor_log_b if data gets inserted during the transaction or the `BEGIN;..COMMIT;` prevent this?

Comment: What does USING (location) do?

Comment: @Paparazzi The USING clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A statement sees a consistent view of the "world" based on the data that was there when the statement started. So the `select` statements in your two insert statements will not see new rows **while they are running**.

However, if the table is changed *between* running the two statement (or after the first one started), each select statement could see different data e.g the first one sees 100 rows, the second one 200.

If you want to ensure that the whole *transaction* sees a consistent view of the data, use a higher [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). In your case using `repeatable read` would be enough.

```
begin transaction isolation level repeatable read;

...
commit;
```

Another option would be to do this in a single statement using a [data modifying cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with to_insert as (
  SELECT id, location 
  FROM sensor_log
  INNER JOIN sensor_location_to_insert USING (location)
), insert_a as (
  insert into sensor_log_a
  select *
  from to_insert
)
insert into sensor_log_b
select *
from to_insert;
```

Comment: "However the view that each select statement has, might be different (e.g the first one sees 100 rows, the second one 200)" if the select are different? I think I don't see properly differences between your two first paragraphs.

Comment: @BeniMio: what I mean is that between running the first and the second statement there might be changes to the underlying table. So the first statement might see different rows then the second. I changed my wording. Is that clearer now?

Comment: @a_hose_with_no_name But it's in contradiction with "So the select statements in your two insert statements will not see new rows."? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Also by default a transaction is `READ COMMITTED` "A statement can only see rows committed before it began. This is the default." it should be enough?

Comment: @BeniMio: a single statement will not see any changes to the underlying tables while it's running. But the **next** statement will see those changes (with "read committed")

Comment: `REPEATABLE READ` is definitely the right choice here.